# What i should to do in didreceivememorywarning

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning

I have an app with feed like instagram. When I scroll it loads more and more images.
So at one moment iOS sent me memory warning and I don't know what i should to do.
If I make array(feed) is equal to nil, nothing happens

here's my object allocations:
[image]

Comment: When you scroll, your app should remove items (notably, image views and their images) from the view that are no longer visible (and remove all strong references to them). Think of the `UITableView` model that reuses cells, only maintaining cells for those rows currently visible. In answer to your question, you really shouldn't generally get a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, but if you do, make sure to purge any caches that you're holding in memory for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

**You are supposed to `dealloc` any unneeded or recreate-able resources**, like some images off of an array in which you might keep of all images your app has downloaded since the creation of mankind*.

**note that this is highly not recommended.*

Comment: I use AFNetworking category for UIImageView and it seems to be cached them

Comment: @wiruzx Look up the docs for AFNetworking and see if there's anything you can do about it. How often do you get these warnings?

Comment: Always when scrolled about 30 posts